# Different templates for Posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a created a custom WordPress Theme.

All the Posts have a different layout and Pages have a different layout.

By default for Posts wordpress uses index.php and content.php

By default for Pages wordpress uses page.php and content-page.php

I have created two different posts.

What I want to know is how to display one post in the page template layout and the other post in post template layout?

Is this possible?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yest this is possible by using a Plugin named - Custom post template.

Here is the link to the plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-template/

Answer (score 0):

No,It is not possible to do.Different Posts is a normal post type called posts.And pages are called Page.
So you can not mess up with pages and posts.Please see wordpress codex templates
http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates

Answer (score 0):

In your template you create a template called template-post.php and template-page.php

At the beginning of the file you need to use

```
 <?php
 /**
 * Template Name: Page Builder
 * Template Post Type: post, page
 * @package WordPress
 */
```

Please note the Template Post Type: post, page.

Now the templates are available for both posts and pages.